# HttpClient executes requests multiple time if request timed out

Tags: java, android, httpclient, connection-timeout

`HttpClient` executes request 4 times if it times out. If it does not time out then it is working fine. Is it related to `HttpClient`?

Comment: Where is code, that execute HttpClient four times !!!

Comment: @Kedarnath I knew the answer and issue was not in my code. So I did not add code. I have posted answer already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that it is `HttpClient`'s default behaviour to execute requests 4 times if it fails. I am not sure about other kind of failures but at least with time out.

To disable this behaviour do this :

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
// Disable default behavior of HttpClient of retrying requests in case of failure
((AbstractHttpClient) client).setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(0, false));
```

Here retry count is set to `0`  to disable retry.

I found solution from [this blog](http://somethingididnotknow.wordpress.com/2013/06/11/httppost-requests-executed-multiple-times-apache-httpclient/).

Answer (score 4):

This resolved the issue for me. Using httpclient 4.3 and above.

```
HttpClientBuilder.create().disableAutomaticRetries().build();
```

Comment: @AliHashemi That should work. Would you mind sharing some code sample or provide more context on how you're trying to use this. it's well documented here http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#disableAutomaticRetries()

Comment: Yes it works. Sorry I forgot to come back and delete this comment. The problem was something else.

Answer (score 3):

Apache HttpClient tries to connect 5 times in case of transport exception. Here is what [doc](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/exception-handling.html) says:

> HttpClient will automatically retry up to 5 times those methods that
>   fail with a transport exception while the HTTP request is still being
>   transmitted to the target server (i.e. the request has not been fully
>   transmitted to the server).

To change this behaviour you need to implement `HttpMethodRetryHandler` interface